# Disable holiday, sundays and past dates inside jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm in creating appointment form with jQuery datepicker. I've search around but seems that I can't combine all function I want in the beforeshowday.
What I want from the datepicker is disabled all date before today (yesterday and the rest of it because you can't make appointment at date before today it must be later), then disabled on  every Sunday (its non working day) and public holiday (this one using array). What I saw from others is the jQuery are specifically for only one function like public holiday it just an array, but how about disabled previous day and sunday?

I tried to follow this articles http://articles.tutorboy.com/2010/09/03/jquery-ui-datepicker-disable-specified-dates/ but I don't know how to combine it. Can someone show me how?

I have this to disabled on every Sunday

```
 function disabledSunday(date) {
     var day = date.getDay();
     return [(day != 0), ''];
 }
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
     beforeShowDay: disabledSunday
 });
```

This one for alldates till today

```
 var date = new Date();
 var m = date.getMonth(),
     d = date.getDate(),
     y = date.getFullYear();
 // Disable all dates till today
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     minDate: new Date(y, m, d),
     dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
 });
```

This one is for specific dates such as public holiday

```
 // Disable a list of dates
 var disabledDays = ["5-31-2013", "6-01-2013"];

 function disableAllTheseDays(date) {
     var m = date.getMonth(),
         d = date.getDate(),
         y = date.getFullYear();
     for (i = 0; i < disabledDays.length; i++) {
         if ($.inArray((m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y, disabledDays) != -1) {
             return [false];
         }
     }
     return [true];
 }
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
     dateFormat: 'mm-dd-yy',
     beforeShowDay: disableAllTheseDays
 });
```

How to combine these three function into one, I'm not much into Jquery and javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :-
     html code :
     `<input id="txtDate" />`

```
function disabledays(date) {
    var ymd = date.getFullYear() + "-" + (date.getMonth() + 1) + "-" + date.getDate();
        //if u have to disable a list of day
         var removeDays = ["2013-6-11","2013-6-31" ];
         if ($.inArray(ymd, removeDays) >= 0) {
        return [false];
    } else {
        //Show accept sundays
        var day = date.getDay();
        return [(day == 1 || day == 2 || day == 3 || day == 4 ||day == 5 ||day == 6 )];
    }
}

$(function () {
    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: disabledays
    });
});
```

Comment: is that only for disabled for sunday isn't it, but how about public holiday and previous date?

Comment: as i you have to specify specific day for public holidays,to let the code know which date has to be disabled.

Comment: I have edited my code where array removeDays hold the list of days to disable.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys I've successfully implement it

Comment: err I want to make the calendar look more attractive, like the list of disableday I want to title or some sort of notation there like public holiday for New year etc, can someone teach me how

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`minDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) option to disable past dates. In addition, you can use [`beforeShowDay`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) option to check the other two conditions**.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            // it is possible to write the following function using one line
            // of code; instead, multiple if/else are used for readability
            var ok = true;
            if (date.getDay() === 0) { // is sunday
                ok = false;
            } else {
                var dateStr = $.datepicker.formatDate("m-dd-yy", date);
                if ($.inArray(dateStr, disabledDays) >= 0) { // is holiday
                    ok = false;
                }
            }
            return [ok, ""];
        }
    });
});
```

** Actually it is possible to check all three conditions in that function.

Comment: Thanks guys i'll try put it in my code will let u guys know when i successfully made it

Answer (score 1):

Try this
`$("#datepicker").datepicker({ minDate: 0 });`

Answer (score 0):

May u will find your slution here

http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max

Comment: I've been there but still can't combine the function